# Laravel - Inertia Error handling - how to redirect to custom error page

Tags: laravel, error-handling, inertiajs

Hello I'm developing a Laravel 10 / Inertia / Vue 3 application.

I want to manage error handling do that in case of error, instead of show the default Inertia modal, I redirect the user to a custom error page.

Here the relevant piece of code I wrote; it does not work as also changing APP_DEBUG to false, and APP_ENV to production, in case of error it writes some lines to the storage/logs/laravel.log file but displays always the Inertia modal with ERROR 500

.ENV file

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of exception types with their corresponding custom log levels.
     *
     * @var array<class-string<\Throwable>, \Psr\Log\LogLevel::*>
     */
    protected $levels = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string<\Throwable>>
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed to the session on validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
     * Prepare exception for rendering.
     *
     * @param  \Throwable  $e
     * @return \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        $response = parent::render($request, $e);

        if (! app()->environment(['local', 'testing']) && in_array($response->getStatusCode(), [500, 503, 404, 403])) {
            return Inertia::render('Error', ['status' => $response->getStatusCode()])
                ->toResponse($request)
                ->setStatusCode($response->getStatusCode());
        } elseif ($response->getStatusCode() === 419) {
            return back()->with([
                'message' => 'The page expired, please try again.',
            ]);
        }

        return $response;
    }

}
```

In my controller I have this block of code:

```
    try {
        // confirm number
        $numero_conferma = Str::random(16);

        // save the data 
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->courses()->attach($request->course, ['submission' => $request->submission, 'numero_conferma' => $numero_conferma, 'tipo_pagamento' => $request->tipo_pagamento, 'ammontare' => $request->ammontare, 'data_registrazione' => now()]);

        return redirect()->route('ft.courses.list', $customer->cid)->with('message', 'Iscrizione effettuata con successo.');
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
       throw $th;
    }
```

In my tests I used to insert a record with the same keys in the pivot table so that it generate a db error; instead of showing my custom error page, it always show the standard Inertia error modal.

Any help?

Comment: Try to clear the config

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct, so I would start by removing the `! app()->environment(['local', 'testing']) &&` to see if you have a caching error. If so, put it back and run `php artisan config:clear`

Another possibility is that your error status code is not being caught as the code is only catching `[500, 503, 404, 403]`

Comment: clearing the config might help